# Perl script is not waiting for a .bat file to complete and continuing execution

Tags: perl

I am calling a bat file from a perl script.
Since the bat file takes long time for execution, the perl script is not waiting for the bat file to complete and continuing execution from the next line.

Is there a way by which we can suspend the execution of the perl script until the bat file is finished execution and then resume once the bat file is done.

I wrote something like this:

```
system ("start $bat_file");
print ("Hello");
```

So it prints hello even before bat file is finished.

Actually what I want to accomplish is:

1. My bat file creates some file
2. I want to copy those files to another location once the bat file is done.

But as it is not waiting for the bat file to complete, the copy fails because it tries to copy a folder which does not exist as the bat file is still being processed and has not produced the output file.

**Note** : Time to complete bat file is not fixed and changes everytime.

Comment: Did you use `system`, `exec`, `qx` or backticks `\``?

Comment: Yes, there is. But it depends a lot on exactly what you're doing. And for that, we're going to need some code examples.

Comment: Yes, I used system.
I wrote something like this:
system("start $bat_file");

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to remove the `start` command

Without the `/wait` option, `start` will create a process and return immediately

But there is no need for `start` at all. You can write just

```
system($bat_file);
```

to achieve the effect that you're asking for

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you have is the problem with `start command` and not with `system`

When you are using `start` command on windows it will start your program but will not wait for ending.

You have to use `/wait` after `start`
In your code it will be :

```
system ("start /wait $bat_file"); 
print ("Hello");`
```

[Start Manual](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: When I used the code which you mentioned, the call never returns back to the caller even after the bat file is finished. It justs stays suspended and never resumes operation after the bat file is finished.
However it is working if I write system($bat_file);